# A 4-dim orientable manifold with different torsions of $H_2$ and $H_1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to ask for an example of a 4-dim *orientable* closed manifold $M^4$ with different torsions of $H_2(M^4,Z)$ and $H_1(M^4,Z)$, ie
$$\text{Tor}(H_2(M^4,Z)) \neq \text{Tor}(H_1(M^4,Z)).$$

Or it is a theorem that $\text{Tor}(H_2(M^4,Z)) = \text{Tor}(H_1(M^4,Z))$ for any 4-dim orientable closed manifold $M^4$.

Comment: Take the product of $S^1$ and $RP^3$. Since it is conformally flat, all Pontryagin forms vanish. Now, compute homology groups using the Kunneth formula.

Comment: Since $
 H_1(S^1\times {R}P^3,Z)=Z\oplus Z_2 ,\
 H_2(S^1\times {R}P^3,Z)=Z_2 ,\
 H_3(S^1\times {R}P^3,Z)=Z 
$, $S^1\times {R}P^3$ is not the 4-dim manifold I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible by Poincaré duality and the universal coefficient theorem.  The former states that for a closed oriented $n$-manifold $M$ we have an isomorphism $H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H^{n-i}(M; \mathbb{Z})$, whilst the latter says basically that cohomology is homology with the torsion shifted up one degree.  In particular, for a closed oriented $4$-manifold the torsion part of $H_1$ is isomorphic to the torsion part of $H^3$ (by Poincaré duality), which is in turn isomorphic to the torsion part of $H_2$ (by the universal coefficient theorem).